# How to change state value in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have problem in changing value of state.It gives mi following error
"Undefine is not a function(evaluating '
   this.setState({
     switchValue:false
})')"

I have search on stack overflow but the solution is not work for me.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Alert,
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Switch
} from 'react-native';

export default class AwesomeProject extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {switchValue: true};

// Toggle the state every second

}
_onPressButton() {  
   this.setState({
   switchValue: false
 });
} 
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.welcome}>
      Welcome to React Native!
    </Text>     
    <Switch 
      onValueChange={this._onPressButton}
      value={this.state.switchValue } 
    />      
  </View>
);
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
   flex: 1,
   justifyContent: 'center',
   alignItems: 'center',
   backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
 welcome: {
   fontSize: 20,
   textAlign: 'center',
  margin: 10,
},
instructions: {
  textAlign: 'center',
  color: '#333333',
  marginBottom: 5,
},
```

});

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

Comment: you can bind your function call like `onValueChange={this._onPressButton.bind(this)}` because your `_onPressButton` need to access `this` as in `this.setState({})`

Answer (score 0):

The `this` inside `_onPressButton` is not referencing the correct reference. On that case, `this` inside that `_onPressButton` is actually reference the button. You can either do this two ways.

```
   <Switch 
      onValueChange={this._onPressButton.bind(this)}
      value={this.state.switchValue } 
    />
```

Or

```
   <Switch 
      onValueChange={() => this._onPressButton()}
      value={this.state.switchValue } 
    />
```